# PigDice game in C#

Tags: c#, beginner, game, dice

In the *C# Player's Guide* book there's a challenge in which you have to write the PigDice game in C#:

> 1. It's a **multiplayer game**, every player starts with **score 0**.
> 2. Player X rolls **2 dice**.
> 3. Player X's score is increased by the **sum of the 2 dice**' numbers.
> 4. If Player X gets **1 on either die, his score becomes 0** again and it's the next player's turn.
> 5. Player X can choose between **play** (roll dice) or **hold** (lose his turn)
> 6. Player X **wins** if his score is equal or greater than N

Is my approach reasonable? How can I improve my program?

[Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/afonsomatos/a4617a5ec80e813c4fa4cb23a6815115)

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PigDice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void CreatePlayers(Player[] players)
        {
            for (int index = 0; index < players.Length; ++index)
            {
                string defaultName = $"Player #{index + 1}";

                Console.Write($"{defaultName}'s name: ");
                string playerName = Console.ReadLine();

                players[index] = new Player(playerName == string.Empty ? defaultName : playerName);
            }
        }

        static void ShowGameStatus(Game game) => Console.WriteLine(game.GetScoresTable());

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to PigDice!");
            Console.Write("Amount of players: ");

            // Number of players that are going to play
            string inputNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            int numberOfPlayers = Convert.ToInt32(inputNumber);

            Game game = new Game(numberOfPlayers);
            Player[] players = game.Players;

            // Ask for and assign players' names
            CreatePlayers(players);

            Console.WriteLine("All set. Let the games begin!");

            // First player starts
            game.PlayingPlayer = players[0];

            // GameLoop returns false if ended
            while (GameLoop(game)) ;

            Console.WriteLine(game.PlayingPlayer + " has won!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static bool GameLoop(Game game)
        {
            Player player = game.PlayingPlayer;

            ShowGameStatus(game);

            if (player.hasWon())
                return false;

            Console.Write($"{player}'s turn! Play (no)? ");

            string playersChoice = Console.ReadLine();

            // Handle player's choice to hold
            if (playersChoice.ToLower() == "no")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{player} chose to hold!");
                game.NextTurn();
                return true;
            }

            // Handle player's choice to play
            Dice dice = new Dice();

            Console.WriteLine($"{player} is rolling the dice!");

            int number1 = dice.Roll();
            int number2 = dice.Roll();

            Console.WriteLine($"{player} got {number1} and {number2}");

            // If one dice got 1, all score is lost
            if (number1 == 1 || number2 == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Bad luck! {player} lost all points!");
                player.OverallScore = 0;
                game.NextTurn();
                return true;
            }

            // Player got a score increase
            int scoreWon = number1 + number2;
            player.OverallScore += scoreWon;

            Console.WriteLine($"{player} got {scoreWon} score and now has {player.OverallScore}");

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Player.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PigDice
{
    class Player
    {
        const int pointsToWin = 50; // instead of 100 which is 
                                    // incredibly hard to get

        public string PlayerName { get; }
        public int OverallScore { get; set; }

        public bool hasWon() => this.OverallScore >= pointsToWin;

        public Player(string playerName)
        {
            this.PlayerName = playerName;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.PlayerName;
        }
    }
}
```

**Game.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PigDice
{
    class Game
    {
        public Player[] Players { get; }
        public int Turn { get; private set; }

        public Player PlayingPlayer { get; set; }

        public Game(int numberOfPlayers)
        {
            Players = new Player[numberOfPlayers];
        }

        public void NextTurn()
        {
            Turn += 1;
            PlayingPlayer = Players[Turn % Players.Length];
        }

        public string GetScoresTable() {
            string table = "----- Scores -----";

            foreach (Player player in Players)
                table += "\n" + player + ": " + player.OverallScore;

            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

**Dice.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PigDice
{
    class Dice
    {
        private Random random = new Random();

        public int Roll() => random.Next(6) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be worth your while to mention in the non-code part of your post that you have adapted the rules to use 50 points to win instead of 100. The description of the problem also says "Player X wins if his score is N" but in your code you made it such that the score has to be "N or more" rather than be exactly N.

Comment: `random.Next(6) + 1;` same as `random.Next(1, 7);`

Comment: @t3chb0t Yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial impression is that there seems to be quite a lot of shared responsibility, particularly between the static methods in `Program` and the rest of the code.  For example:

```
private static bool GameLoop(Game game)
```

This really seems like it should belong in your `Game` class.  It's also odd that this function doesn't actually contain the loop, so you have to call it from within one:

```
while (GameLoop(game)) ;
```

This seems counter intuitive.  Perhaps it should be `GetRound` or something and called by `GameLoop` where both of them sit in the `Game` class...

**Player Construction**

`Game` contains an array of players, which it creates on construction, however it isn't responsible for populating the players.   This tightly couples the `Game` class to `CreatePlayers` in your `Program` class.  If `GetScoresTable` is called before the players are created the program will crash.

A better approach might be to have `CreatePlayers` actually create an array of players and then have the array passed into the constructor of `Game`, rather than the number of players.  That way, `Game` is in a completely constructed state and is ready for other methods on the class to be called.